# SQL - Counting from distinct pairs

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table representing sending msgs between friends on FB:

```
    Sender    Receiver   Msgs #

     Dave       John        6     
     John       Dave        1    
     Sam        Dave        2   
     Mark       Ash         1    
     Ash        Dave        3 
     Mark       Steve       8
```

What is an SQL query to show how many have 1,2,3... friends:

```
    Num of friends       Quantity
          1                 3
          2                 2
          3                 1
```

I have tried using a loop, but it just gets too complicated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a couple of sub-queries to achieve this by following an approach like this:

1. List of all unique senders and receivers.
2. Count of the number of friends per unique sender.
3. Group the number of friends and count how many occurrences there are.

Here's some code that shows it working (obviously field names need to change to match your actual table):

```
CREATE TABLE msgs (Sender VARCHAR(20), Receiver VARCHAR(20), Msgs INT);

INSERT INTO msgs VALUES ('Dave', 'John', 6), ('John', 'Dave', 1),('Sam', 'Dave', 2),('Mark', 'Ash', 1),   ('Ash', 'Dave', 3),('Mark', 'Steve', 8);

SELECT  FriendCount AS `Num of friends`,
        COUNT(*) AS Quantity
  FROM  (
        SELECT  Sender,
                COUNT(*) AS FriendCount
          FROM  (
                SELECT DISTINCT
                        Sender,
                        Receiver
                  FROM  msgs
                UNION
                SELECT DISTINCT
                        Receiver,
                        Sender
                  FROM  msgs
                ) a
          GROUP BY Sender
        ) a
  GROUP BY FriendCount
  ORDER BY FriendCount;

DROP TABLE msgs;
```

Output:

```
Num of friends   Quantity
1                3
2                2
3                1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming two people exchanging a messages means each is a friend of the other, you can get who is a friend of whom with:

```
select Sender as user, Receiver as friend from msgs
union distinct
select Receiver, Sender from msgs
```

From that, you can then get a count of how many friends each user has:

```
select user, count(*) as friends
from (
    select Sender as user, Receiver as friend from msgs
    union distinct
    select Receiver, Sender from msgs
) user_friends
group by user
```

And from that, get your count of counts:

```
select friends, count(*)
from (
    select user, count(*) as friends
    from (
        select Sender as user, Receiver as friend from msgs
        union distinct
        select Receiver, Sender from msgs
    ) user_friends
    group by user
) user_num_friends
group by friends
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=0c4226603148f2db0a861f5cfada0d83)

Answer (score 0):

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS msgs;
 
 CREATE TABLE msgs 
 (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
 ,sender VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 ,receiver VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
 );
 
 INSERT INTO msgs VALUES
 (1,'Dave','John'),
 (2,'John','Dave'),
 (3,'Sam','Dave'),
 (4,'Mark','Ash'),
 (5,'Ash','Dave'),
 (6,'Mark','Steve');
```

...

```
SELECT num_of_friends
     , COUNT(*) qty
  FROM 
     ( SELECT a.user
            , COUNT(*) num_of_friends
         FROM
            ( SELECT sender user, receiver friend FROM msgs
               UNION DISTINCT
              SELECT receiver, sender FROM msgs
            ) a
        GROUP 
           BY user
     ) x
 GROUP
    BY num_of_friends;
    
+----------------+-----+
| num_of_friends | qty |
+----------------+-----+
|              1 |   3 |
|              2 |   2 |
|              3 |   1 |
+----------------+-----+
```

To understand what this query is doing 'under-the-hood' just run the innermost query on its own, then the next level, then the next level.